# how to verify ConcurrentHashMap is threadsafe?

Tags: java, concurrency

As the jdk doc said, ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe and it doesn't block multiple thread read. It is not necessary to doubt that since it was under many and restricted test. But I just curious how to tell and write code to verify that.

**Edited**: to be more precisely

1. how to keep read consitent without read block
2. does it return the latest view of data

Comment: recommended reading: **[Testing Concurrent Software](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2010/cmsc433/lectures/TestingConcurrentCode_JavaOne2007.pdf)**, a lecture by Bill Pugh and Brian Goetz at Java One '2007. _"By a combination of multiple techniques (careful design, static analysis, code review, extensive testing), you can get the upper hand on concurrency bugs..."_. Pugh and Goetz are among major contributors to API you ask about, members of expert groups for [JSR 133](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133) Memory Model and [JSR 166](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166) Concurrent Utilities

Answer (score 5):

To all practical purposes, you can't.  You can run a number of successful tests numerous times, then without making a change, a test will fail. This is what makes testing multi-threading hard - it is not deterministic.

You may be able to test to an acceptable degree of certainty using statistical methods i.e. we ran 10^y randomized tests with no faults found- it is statistically probable that there are no defects.

You cannot run a test that guarantees thread safety, it has to be done by design and white box testing that the design has been implemented correctly.

As far as  ConcurrentHashMap - if your vendor says something is thread safe, you can only decide, do I trust my vendor - or perhaps paraphrasing a great movie line "You've got to ask yourself one question: Do I feel lucky? Well, do ya, punk?" - and if you don't trust your vendor, I think maybe you have bigger problems.

EDIT: My background involves Life critical and Hard Real time (sub nanosecond) embedded systems. My questions is answered in the context of "Whats the worst that happens" being somewhat more important than "an unexplained software crash"......

Comment: I would disagree, I've ensured locking was occurring before by having a sleep in a mock object called inside that lock, the sleep was for 3 seconds and I verified by a mock object that stopped a stopwatch given to the other thread that it was waiting at the lock for 3 seconds, and with timestamps before exiting the lock for thread one I showed thread 2 only entered the lock afterwards. Furthermore you can do tricks by having your tests access the lock object which can give you proofs of behaviors in regards to it. Locking it and executing operations can ensure they aren't blocking operations.

Comment: Granted these techniques I mention aren't faultless 100% deterministic proof guarantees, but they are pretty solid and definitely worth encouraging.

Comment: @Jimmy : All you did was ensure that once successfully locked no other object was able to access the locked object. You do not appear to test obtaining a lock was atomic, and guaranteed to fail if another object simultaneously obtained a lock. I pity your customers if you think your testing is proof that your locking is working.....

Comment: No, I would be ensuring that once locked no other object was able to execute the operation by attempting to execute it. Mock objects are the key to knowing where threads are at any given point in the execution to ensure they are waiting on a lock or inside of a lock at various points in time. And I just said it's not *proof* but it is solid evidence done correctly. If I lock a lock object and execute an operation I want to be blocking and can show with a mock object inside the lock that thread does not hit until I release my lock, that's solid evidence the operation was blocking as I wanted.

Comment: Do you think I refer to locking the whole object? I'm not brain dead, I'm referring to the lock object the blocking operations use being exposed and accessible so my tests can lock that, not the entire object the operation exists in, just the object I expect them to use for locking.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you really never need to go around unit testing frameworks, especially not the main framework of a language.

Unit testing verification's for thread safety can be a little tricky, especially if you aren't super clear on handling threading/concurrency. Also you generally don't get 100% faultless guarantees (though for some scenarios you can), but you can get damn-good using appropriate techniques.

That said, it's a matter of defining the behaviors you don't want and attempting to cause them, then having tests that ensure the desired behavior was at play instead.

For this particular scenario with the steps I laid out you need to:

- Define the beheaviors you don't want: You don't want reads to be blocked.
- Attempt to cause them: Create two threads that try to read from the dictionary at the exact same time (use a signal or timestamp based event for both of them).
- Test the desired behaviour is in play instead: timestamp before and after the read operation, ensure the timestamps started and ended with overlaps between the two threads.

This is a subpar approach though because you're testing for thread safety something where you don't have access to the guts of the system, when you write your own threading systems the trick is to force operations to take longer in the test cases. Normally I put mock objects in the middle of the lock or non-locking operations and force sleeps then ensure the timestamps do or don't overlap as expected depending on if I do want to see locking or don't want to see locking.

Comment: I just wonder why it can keep consistent without read lock

Answer (score 3):

> But I just curious how to tell and write code to verify that.

It depends what you mean by "verify".  The normal Computer Science meaning of "verify" is to show that something is true / correct ... all of the time, not just some or most of the time.

In some cases, it is possible to show thing is true (e.g. certain invariants are always satisfied) purely by testing.  But the only way to do that *by testing* is to test for all possible inputs / starting conditions; i.e. by *exhaustive* testing  In cases which involve multi-threaded behaviour, it is usually not possible to do this.

This is not to say that testing is useless for multi-threaded applications.  But as someone said (Tony Hoare?) testing can prove the presence of bugs, but not the absence of bugs.  Testing alone is simply NOT SUFFICIENT to *verify* correctness of multi-threaded code.

---

The only way to verify (in the accepted sense) that `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe is to analyse the source code, and construct a formal or informal proof of correctness for the thread-safety criteria.  That is hard work.  And on top of that "thread-safety" is actually a rather difficult concept to tie down in a formal sense.  (Basically, it means "works correctly when there are multiple threads" ... which begs the question - what does "works correctly" mean?

Comment: If I lock an object then execute an operation and the operation completes I have just verified completely that operation doesn't block on that lock object. Proofs are possible with multithreading, you just have to recognize what you're proving and the limits of that proof; in this test it doesn't prove it's not a blocking operation, just that it doesn't block on that object, which may be a proof we want. For instance if locking that object could cause a dead lock due to another operation we know blocks on it, that test proves the operation won't enter that specific deadlock scenario.

Comment: *"If I lock an object then execute an operation and the operation completes I have just verified completely that operation doesn't block on that lock object."* - Maybe ... but you have NOT verified that the object is thread-safe.  The operation that does no locking or synchronization whatsoever would also "pass" your test.

Comment: I never said anything about thread-safety. Thread-safety itself is a very nebulous thing, like I said, it is possible to verify behaviors of multi-threaded code, but you just have to understand multi-threading and concurrency well enough to recognize what exactly is being verified. It's likely impossible to ever verify "thread-safety" because that's not a definable behavior, rather it varies from one scenario to another, but you *can* test to verify various behaviors of your code in regards to threading such as the scenario I detailed in my comment.

Comment: Oh I get it.  You are nit-picking that there are *some* things that you can adequately test in a multi-threaded program.  But this only with white-box testing; i.e. testing combined with reasoning to show that what you are testing is equivalent to verification.  And it only applies to certain things.  And it is only as good as the programmer's (informal) reasoning ... and that can be just as buggy as his / her code.

Comment: Yes; I am "nit-picking" because I don't like seeing people blanket discouraged from even trying something when as you just admitted, there are things that you can do. Also it occurs to me you may have been thinking of "testing" as manual; I presume the OP meant unit testing from the beginning because he mentioned a specific class. I'm not advocating the belief that you can get perfect multi-threading proofs with unit testing either, just that you shouldn't give up out right (or tell others to) and not even try to come up with some tests.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - what I'm trying to get across is the simple fact that testing is NOT verification.  I have not stated or implied that you shouldn't write any tests.  What I have stated is that testing alone is NOT SUFFICIENT for verifying thread-safety, particularly for complicated classes like ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Fair enough, I tend to take "verification" as the industry meaning where it's just a synonym for well-tested rather than the academic sense. Nobody in industry does real "verification", save for an extremely small number of places. So yes I agree to your point thread behavior cannot be "verified" without source. Though on a side note, in the academic sense, can you ever "verify" anything without combing the source and constructing a formal proof based on it?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - returning to something you said earlier.  *"If I lock an object then execute an operation and the operation completes I have just verified completely that operation doesn't block on that lock object."*.  Actually you haven't.  All you have "verified" is that that operation made with all of the overt and hidden variables in the state that they are in that the operation does not block on the lock.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said. Like I said, you must be aware of what you're actually verifying, but it is a verification, just not a broad one. As for what you're referring to in background state, again the verification technique I'm referring to presumes you have the source code because you're its author and writing unit tests for it. Given that, I also presume you wrote decent code with low dependency count and are capable of abstracting the dependencies out of the code for proper unit testing with mocks that tests the literal unit and nothing more.

Comment: How to properly write code so that it is unit testable to a high level of guarantees (not necessarily 100%) is a whole different topic, one very near and dear to me as I do believe in the value of such good tests that reach towards verification. That said, I would also say high quality unit testing of this sort is rare as people largely don't know how to write code that can be unit tested in this fashion, perhaps this is why I'm touchy on the topic, people often give in to the "it can't be done" belief long before putting in the effort to find out you can write testable code.